# How do you configure Solr to produce a result set with most common words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I'm creating article search functionality for my application. I am looking for search functionality similar to Stackoverflow's Question creation suggestions that popup below the title textbox when you create a new Question.

Search String:

```
"the dog waker"
```

Database Rows:

```
"The best you can do"
"Love to your pet"
"Selina the dog walker"
"How to teach your dog to be healthy" 
"Teach your dog tricks"
```

I want each word in the input to make an impact on the resultset and if the input word is not found it doesn't filter out the dataset i'm searching.

I want to get this resultset:

`"Selina the dog walker"` - has "dog" and fuzzy searched "walker" from the input "waker"
`"How to teach your dog to be healthy"` - has "dog"
`"Teach your dog tricks"` - has "dog"

I've modified the schema.xml with the following but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  It filters out everything unless I have all of the words.

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>     -->    
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, you want the ignored rows to appear in the result ?

Comment: I would like the get the resultset because those three rows have "dog" in them, and "Selina the dog walker" has "walker".  I would like to ignore the other two because they don't have any of the words I had in the input search string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do here, but I would remove EdgeNGramFilterFactory and if you want to add some fuzzyness, you can add a [PhoneticFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory) or use the Lucene syntax ~

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
```

(btw, are you aware that you have a closing XML comment at the end of this line)

On the other hand, I know that on Solr 4, the following works:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt " enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
```

I don't think you need:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

Finally, "Love to your pet" should not show up in the results, do you confirm that ?